# java fx loop still freeze the window

Tags: java, loops, javafx, jsoup, javafx-webengine

I have a simple webbrowser in Javafx(WebEngine) and I need a loop which scroll on bottom of page while not show current element... But my code still causing freeze of window...

Here my loop

```
 Document doc;
 Element div;
 do{
   webEngine.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");    
   doc = Jsoup.parse((String) webEngine.executeScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML"));
   div = doc.select("div#browse_end_of_results_footer").first();
 }
 while(div == null);
```

Can anybody help me ? 
Sorry for my English

Comment: Without more info about the page you try to access this is hard to answer. Are you sure that the footer element is eventually shown? What do you see when running your code? Does the browser window scroll as expected? Does that result in new DOM elements to be rendered? You could try to print out the doc in each loop to see what you got... Any StackTrace?

Comment: @luksch I wanna get all results from Facebook search but its loading via Ajax and I must simulate scroll to bottom of page until this div not show. 
when i run this code App only freeze. 
I try used Thread now but its throws Exception: 
"Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-17" 
I work on it now. 
Thank you for your interest